# Probability optimization

Tags: r, optimization

I have the data set

```
d<-data.frame(id=1:100, pr.a=runif(100,min=0, max=0.40))
d$pr.b=d$pr.a+runif(100,min=0, max=0.1))
d$pr.c=d$pr.b+runif(100,min=0, max=0.1)
```

pr.a < pr.b < pr.c are the probability of a success of a binomial trial for tests A, B, C on individuals  (id's )

additionally

```
cost.a<-80; cost.b=200; cost.c=600;
```

The tests A,B,C can be performed multiple times in each subject. So that for example for if IDx has a pr.a =0.2, then if I do this test 2 times i would expect a success probability of `1-pbinom(0,2,0.2)`=0.36 at a cost of `2*cost.a` =160

For each modality A, B, C, in all IDs I would like to find the distributions of the costs that would be required for a given target success rate (lets say `target=0.9`)

At first i would like to see the distributions of the costs if only one test type (only A's or only C's) is applied in each subject (albeit it can be performed multiple times on the same subject).

Additionally I would like to find if combination of types can minimize the cost for a target success rate.

This seems to me as an optimization problem. I have no experience on optimization. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could characterize this as an optimization problem, but only a very simple one. You are simply trying to maximize the probability per unit cost. To calculate this, simply divide the probability by the cost:

```
d$pr.a / cost.a # The probability per unit cost for A
d$pr.b / cost.b
d$pr.c / cost.c
```

Pick the maximum for each id, and you will get the 'best' test for each id. To calculate the expected cost for a given probability just divide the `target` by the `probability` and multiply by `cost`.

```
target=0.9
(target / d$pr.ca) * cost
```